# MSE of an estimator

Tags: estimation

In the book *Fundamentals of Statistical Processing, Volume I: Estimation Theory* by Steven M. Kay on page 19, it say that the mean square error of an estimator, $\hat{\theta}$, given the true value, $\theta$, is defined as

\begin{align}
\text{mse}(\hat{\theta}) &= E[(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2] \\
&= E \left[ \left[\left( \hat{\theta} - E[\hat{\theta}] \right) + \left( E[\hat{\theta}] - \theta \right) \right]^2 \right]\\
&= \text{var}(\hat{\theta}) + b^2(\theta)
\end{align}
where $b(\theta) = E[\hat{\theta}] - \theta$ is the bias.

But if I write it out, it doesn't come out to be the same

\begin{align}
\text{mse}(\hat{\theta}) &= E[(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2] \\
&= E \left[ \left[\left( \hat{\theta} - E[\hat{\theta}] \right) + \left( E[\hat{\theta}] - \theta \right) \right]^2 \right]\\
&= E \left[ \left( \hat{\theta} - E[\hat{\theta}] \right)^2 + \left( E[\hat{\theta}] - \theta \right)^2 + 2 \left( \hat{\theta} - E[\hat{\theta}] \right) \left( E[\hat{\theta}] - \theta \right) \right]\\
&= \text{var}(\hat{\theta}) + b^2(\theta) +  2 E \left[\left( \hat{\theta} - E[\hat{\theta}] \right) \left( E[\hat{\theta}] - \theta \right) \right]
\end{align}

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$
E\left[\hat \theta - E\left(\hat \theta \right)\right] = E\left(\hat \theta\right) - E\left(\hat \theta\right) 
$$

Comment: well now i feel stupid :) thanks anyways

Comment: It's important that $\theta$ is modeled as a deterministic parameter rather than a random variable. That's why we can take the other factor out of the expectation.

Comment: @MattL. yeah...i just didn't even think about expanding further and stopped like in the question...thanks :)

Comment: @MattL. It is indeed true that for *classical estimation* (contrary to *Bayesian*)  $\theta$ is deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to point out here that Kay is talking about *classical estimation*, which means that the parameters to be estimated are unknown but deterministic. Hence, the term $E[\hat{\theta}]-\theta$ is deterministic, and, consequently, the last term in your equation becomes

$$\begin{align} E \left[\left( \hat{\theta} - E[\hat{\theta}] \right) \left( E[\hat{\theta}] - \theta \right) \right]&= \left(E[\hat{\theta}]-\theta\right)E\left[\hat{\theta}-E[\hat{\theta}]\right]\\&=\left(E[\hat{\theta}]-\theta\right)\left(E[\hat{\theta}]-E[\hat{\theta}]\right)
\\&=0\end{align}$$